# Converting Excel MAcro from 32 Bit to 64 Bit

Tags: excel, vba

I have a quite large excel macro written in 32bit and need to convert to use n excel 64 bit. Is there an easy way to do this conversion? 
It is a large macro and not possible to convert line by line.

I have included part of the code below.

```
'32-bit API declarations
Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long

Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As Long

Sub DisplayDirectoryDialogBox()
    Dim Msg As String
    FileCount = 0
    Msg = "Select a location containing the files you want to list."
    SelectedDir = GetDirectory(Msg)
    If SelectedDir = "" Then End
    With Application
        .StatusBar = "WAIT..."
        .ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: Manually add `PtrSafe` to all declarations. Manually convert all `Long`s in the declarations that represent pointers to `LongPtr`s (in the code shown, that would be only `pidl`). Manually update declarations of `Long` variables in procedures that are passed as these parameters to `LongPtr`. There's no other way. You may try to look into refactoring tools/addins that may automate the replacements to a degree.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @GSerg seems to work fine. Please put it in answer box and I accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Gserg:

Manually add PtrSafe to all declarations. Manually convert all Longs in the declarations that represent pointers to LongPtrs (in the code shown, that would be only pidl). Manually update declarations of Long variables in procedures that are passed as these parameters to LongPtr. There's no other way. You may try to look into refactoring tools/addins that may automate the replacements to a degree. – GSerg Jul 18 at 8:55