# Trying to convert 32-Bit Excel Macros into 64-Bit

Tags: excel, vba, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to run an Excel loaded with multiple macros. It was written for a 32-Bit and work upgraded me to a 64-Bit to do Power BI reporting.

The Excel macros are spitting out errors. I tried to use other threads to help me convert it. However I keep having the debugger come back to me about the last line.

I found this comment on a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161901/converting-excel-macro-from-32-bit-to-64-bit) and used it as a guideline to alter my code and was able to remove some of the data type errors I was being thrown.

> Manually add `PtrSafe` to all declarations. Manually convert all `Long`s in the declarations that represent pointers to `LongPtr`s (in the code shown, that would be only `pidl`). Manually update declarations of `Long` variables in procedures that are passed as these parameters to `LongPtr`. There's no other way. You may try to look into refactoring tools/addins that may automate the replacements to a degree.

```vb
Set objmyconn = New ADODB.Connection
Set Objmycmd = New ADODB. Connection
Set obmyrecordset= New ADODB.Recordset
objmyconn.ConnectionTImeout = 0 
objmyconn.Open "DSN=UU####; uid=NAME; pwd:1234"
```

```
Run-time error '2147467259 (80004005)':
```

Comment: Check your Integer variables too; and watch out for number of rows being greater than 65,535, etc.  What are some of the errors?

Comment: [Possibility related](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/971987/error-message-when-you-use-an-adodb-connection-object-with-an-odbc-dri&ved=2ahUKEwi308ma-rfkAhVc7nMBHbj9DQAQFjABegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw0iVXGRMwzBwnxGW7lGoblY&cshid=1567627323090)

Comment: @MarkStewart The limits for the data types are exactly the same between 32 and 64 bit Excel. The number of rows is also the same.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Please use [direct links](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/971987/error-message-when-you-use-an-adodb-connection-object-with-an-odbc-dri) instead of the mangled tracking links that Google gives on the results page.